# Perform add operation using Generic Concept

Tags: c#

I have a class of generic type which accepts 2 parameters .
 now I need to add these two parameter values and return back the result.

```
class AddValue<TText, TValue>

    {
        public AddValue(TText text, TValue value)
        {
            Text = text;
            Value = value;

        }
        public TText Text { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: By `Add` do you `Numeric`, `Concatenation`, or whatever the `+ Operator` is programmed to do?  The only one that can be done without some form of reflection is concat.

Comment: When you say Add, do you mean Sum? Or Add as a member?

Comment: i need to add the value. how  would  i return  back the result  to the calling function

Answer (score 3):

If you literally mean Add, as in `TText + TValue` then you have two options here:

1. You can force them to implement an interface that has an Add method (or whatever), and call that, or
2. Have the caller pass a delegate that does the addition.

Since unbounded generic type-parameters are effectively `object` references, you can't operate on them directly. Instead, get the calling code to do the heavy lifting, since they know what to do.